# how to get a shmid from a boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory object

Tags: c++, boost, shared-memory, boost-interprocess

boost::interprocess will create a shm like this:

```
boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory segment(boost::interprocess::open_or_create, "ContainerSharedMemory", 65536);
```

but how can a watch this shm like this:

```
/Tool/SHMCache$ ipcs -m

key        shmid      owner      perms      bytes      nattch     status      
0x00005feb 0          root       666        12000      2                       
0x00005fe7 32769      root       666        524288     2                       
0x00005fe8 65538      root       666        2097152    2                       
0x0001c08e 98307      root       777        2072       0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`managed_shared_memory` is for cross-platform use which uses a `BasicManagedMemoryImpl` pointer to internal implementation on different OSes. For example, it  uses `basic_managed_windows_shared_memory` as backend on Windows. `managed_shared_memory` doesn't have a method to get shmid for the sake of portability. If you OS supports system V shared memory, you can use `basic_managed_xsi_shared_memory` which has `get_shmid()` method and nearly the same interface as `basic_managed_shared_memory`. A simple example:

```
#include <boost/interprocess/xsi_shared_memory.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/mapped_region.hpp>

using namespace boost::interprocess;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //Build XSI key (ftok based)
    xsi_key key(argv[0], 1);
    //Create a shared memory object.
    xsi_shared_memory shm (create_only, key, 1000);
    // TODO Remove if exists
    printf("shmid: %d\n", shm.get_shmid());
}
```

Then you can see it with `ipcs -m` if share memory is created successfully.

Comment: System V is fully supported by Linux kernels. Of course you can run the simple program on linux.

Comment: thanks，i will try this. and how can i get more detail about managed_shared_memory

Comment: [boost docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/interprocess/managed_memory_segments.html#interprocess.managed_memory_segments.managed_shared_memory.windows_managed_memory_common_shm) talk a little about this.